# Check number of query after use limit SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL.

I have a query like

```
select * from mytable order by 1 desc limit 2
```

If mytable has only 1 row this query will return that row. How can I make sure my query always return 2 result and if mytable has 1 row it will return NULL

That's my 1st question here, sorry for my English

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a union trick here:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, 1 AS priority FROM mytable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, 2
) t
ORDER BY
    priority,
    col1
LIMIT 2;
```

The above strategy is to include via union two "empty" records.  However, these empty records would only ever appear in the result set in the event that your table has fewer than 2 records.

Comment: Can you explain why we need two "empty" records? What's different if I use only 1? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I only include two empty records to ensure that you always have a result set of size 2, even in the event that the table be completely empty.  If you are certain that your table would always have at least one record, then you only need to union once with a single "empty" record.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of columns and don't want to list them, you can use this variation on Tim's answer:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
union all
select t.*
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n) left join
     mytable t
     on 1 = 0;  -- always false
order by col1 desc
limit 2;
```

The descending sort puts non-`NULL` values first.  This assumes that `col1` is not `NULL` -- so valid rows are first.

Notes:

- This makes it easy to add more rows (just change the subquery).
- This makes it easy to handle more columns -- they are inserted automatically.
- No subquery is needed.